# how to read a cookie from a php, when the cookie was set on a different sub-domain?

Tags: php, jquery, cookies

I have 2 sub-domains: 'secure' and 'downloads' of the same domain: "10.0.50.18".

on 'downloads' I set a cookie using jQuery like this:

```
$.cookie("width", w, {domain: "10.0.50.18"});
```

on 'secure', i am trying to read that cookie like this:

```
$width = $_COOKIE["width"];
```

yet it is not working.

can anyone help please?
Thank you!

Comment: bcoz subdomain names are different

Answer (score 2):

Cookies wont work across subdomains unless you specify when creating the cookie. You will need to do something like this:

```
$.cookie("width", w, {domain: ".mydomain.com"});
```

This will allow all sub domains of mydomain.com to share the cookie.

Comment: Well put. I'd add that if your "secure" subdomain is a different protocol (https instead of http, for example), you still might run into issues. You can can read http cookies from https, but not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks, but if you look at my question, this is exactly what i said I was doing already...

Comment: Its not the same as what you are doing. You are putting a IP address in the domain part. This just will not work. Cookies work with domain hosts. Please note the . before the domain name, this allows for subdomains.

Comment: so if the full addresses for my site is: https://10.0.50.18/secure/welcome.php and https://10.0.50.18/downloads/games.html, what should i pass the cookie?
".download"?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it is impossible to use cookies from different domains the way you are trying.
some interesting proposals of solutions you can read here
[Cross-Domain Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies)

Comment: He is trying against different sub-domains which *is* allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* set a cookie to an IP address, you just cannot use wildcards with it.

```
domain .10.0.50.18 is not valid
domain 10.0.50.18 is valid
```

IP addresses do not easily follow organizational boundaries in the way DNS domains do. An IP address with a number one less or one greater than the IP address of the web server may not necessarily reside in the same organization. For security reasons any form of wild-carding of IP addresses in the domain attribute of a cookie is not permitted. This effectively removes the usefulness of the domain attribute for any form of IP address.

From http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt

> Fully-qualified host name (FQHN) means either the fully-qualified
>      domain name (FQDN) of a host (i.e., a completely specified domain
>      name ending in a top-level domain such as .com or .uk), or the
>      numeric Internet Protocol (IP) address of a host.  The fully
>      qualified domain name is preferred; ***use of numeric IP addresses is
>      strongly discouraged***.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Only thing is, I wasn't using .10.0.50.18 but 10.0.50.18, which you said was suppose to be fine - yet it does not work...
what if my FQHN is: https://10.0.50.18/secure/welcome.php
what should i pass as the domain for the $.cookie() method?

Comment: Your FQDN is not the IP address - it is your actual domain name.

Comment: With an IP how do you expect to address a sub-domain @yogev?